# Keep empty values

Tags: entities

I have the following case: I have a field (Long text) with unlimited values. Now I have the following values:

```
Value 1
- empty value -
Value 3
```

By default, the second value would get removed. How can I prevent that? I don't really need a remove button, but that would be the cleanest way.

**Update:**
Okay, I' now trying with a custom field type. Thanks to Clive. The field is available, the fields are getting generated, but the values are not saved. Do I need a custom validation and submit function?

My code so far:
si_media.install

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_field_scheme().
 */
function si_media_field_scheme($field) {
  $schema = array(
    'columns' => array(
      'info_id' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'file_id' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => FALSE,
      ),
      'node_id' => array(
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => TRUE,
        'not null' => FALSE,
      ),
      'text_field' => array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'size' => 'big',
        'not null' => FALSE,
      )
    ),
    'indexes' => array(
      'info_id' => array('info_id'),
    ),
    'foreign keys' => array(),
  );

  return $schema;
}
```

si_media.module

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_field_info().
 */
function si_media_field_info() {
  // Define new field type.
  return array(
    'si_media_additional_info' => array(
      'label'             => t('Additional informations'),
      'description'       => t('Field to provide additional informations for images'),
      'default_widget'    => 'si_media_field_widget',
      'default_formatter' => 'si_media_field_formatter',
      'settings'          => array(),
      'instance_settings' => array(),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_info().
 */
function si_media_field_formatter_info() {
  // Define new display formatter.
  return array(
    'si_media_field_formatter' => array(
      'label'       => t('SI Media Formatter'),
      'field types' => array('si_media_additional_info'),
    ),
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_formatter_view().
 */
function si_media_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $language, $items, $display) {
  $element = array();

  switch ($display['type']) {
    case 'si_media_field_formatter':
      $element[]['#markup'] = var_export($items, true);
      break;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form().
 */
function si_media_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $language, $items, $delta, $element) {
  switch ($instance['widget']['type']) {
    case 'si_media_field_widget':
      $element['text_field'] = array(
        '#type'           => 'text_format',
        '#maxlength'      => 500,
        '#title'          => $instance['label'],
        '#default_value'  => isset($items[$delta]['text']) ? $items[$delta]['text'] : NULL,
        '#required'       => $element['#required'],
        '#weight'         => $element['#weight'],
        '#size'           => 'big',
      );

      $element['si_media_additional_info_removed'] = array(
        '#type'           => 'hidden',
        '#value'          => '0',
      );

      break;
  }

  return $element;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_widget_error().
 */
function si_media_widget_error($element, $error, $form, &$form_state) {
  switch ($error['error']) {
    case 'si_media_field_invalid':
      form_error($element, $error['message']);
      break;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_is_empty().
 */
function si_media_field_is_empty($item, $field) {
  return FALSE;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_info().
 */
function si_media_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
    'si_media_field_widget' => array(
      'label' => t('Long Text'),
      'field types' => array('si_media_additional_info'),
      'settings' => array(),
      'behaviors' => array(
        'default value' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_NONE,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

What am I missing? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You'll need to define your own custom field type and use that instead of the core text field - [`text_field_is_empty()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!modules!text!text.module/function/text_field_is_empty/7) decides what an 'empty' text field is, essentially anything where `value` is an empty string. I don't think there's any way to override that function without hacking core, so a new field type would probably be the easiest way

Comment: Thanks Clive! Can you provide me some information how to create a new field type?

Comment: There's an excellent example in the [Examples module](http://drupal.org/project/examples), and [this question/answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35191/creating-a-custom-field-widget) should shed some light too. If you get stuck at any point just pop back here with your code and I'm sure someone will point you in the right direction :)

Comment: Thanks again, Clive. I'm facing one last problem (I think). If you want, you can create an answer to my question (as you already did in the comments)